# List of Spreadsheets Gdata OAuth2

Tags: gdata, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-apps-marketplace

Getting a list of spreadsheets with spreadsheet api in Gdata,

Oauth1 Way

```
spreadSheetService = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
spreadSheetService.SetOAuthInputParameters(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1,self.CONSUMER_KEY,self.CONSUMER_SECRET,two_legged_oauth=True, requestor_id=self.requestor_id)
spreadSheetService.GetSpreadsheetsFeed(query = q)
```

But since spreadSheetService is not available for OAuth2 because of this [won't fix issue #594](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=594)

How do I query for a list of spreadsheets with `gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetClient` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(assuming Python)

I was able to use `gd_client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)` to take a credentials object created by an OAuth2 flow (using the oauth2client) and use this with the gdata library.

Full example here (for a command-line app):

```
# Do OAuth2 stuff to create credentials object
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run

storage = Storage("creds.dat")
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow_from_clientsecrets("client_secrets.json", scope=["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]), storage)

# Use it within gdata
import gdata.spreadsheets.client
import gdata.gauth

gd_client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
gd_client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
print gd_client.get_spreadsheets()
```

If you're specifically looking for 2-legged, the same technique works, but you will need to create a different type of credentials object. See the following recent answer regarding how to create this: [Using Spreadsheet API OAuth2 with Certificate Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209178/using-spreadsheet-api-oauth2-with-certificate-authentication/20211057#20211057)

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that you can query for a specific spreadsheet by passing an instance `SpreadSheetQuery` as a named argument `query`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation that writes an OAuth 2.0 Bearer auth header directly to the request and allows you to continue to use the older `gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService` style client code:

```
import httplib2
# Do OAuth2 stuff to create credentials object
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import tools

storage = Storage("creds.dat")
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets("client_secrets.json", scope=["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"])
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
if credentials.access_token_expired:
    credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())

# Use it within old gdata
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import gdata.service

client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService(
    additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % credentials.access_token})

#public example
entry = client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed('0AoFkkLP2MB8kdFd4bEJ5VzR2RVdBQkVuSW91WE1zZkE') 
print entry.title
```